# How to convert milliseconds to hh mm ss format and save it in Db

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

How can we show milliseconds to hh:mm:ss format.

The result from all attempt I made simply shows 00:00:00:016 or 00:00:00:01320000

Controller Action Method

```
using(Db db = new Db())
{
    Chat newDTO = db.Chats.Where(x => x.ChatId == id).FirstOrDefault();

    DateTime startTime = Convert.ToDateTime(newDTO.FeedbackDateTime);
    DateTime endtime = Convert.ToDateTime(newDTO.FeedbackSharedDateTime);
    TimeSpan duration = endtime - startTime;
    //hh:mm:ss
    string stringAHT = duration.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss\:fff");

    newDTO.AuditorAHT = stringAHT;                

    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

View

```
<div class="form-row">

    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label class="control-label col-md-6 font-weight-bold">AHT</label>
        <div class="col-md-10 bg-gray-200 form-control">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.AuditorAHT)
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: What are the datatypes and values of newDTO.FeedbackDateTime and newDTO.FeedbackSharedDateTime?

Comment: public DateTime? FeedbackDateTime { get; set; }, public DateTime?FeedbackSharedDateTime { get; set; }. So public DateTime? FeedbackDateTime { get; set; }MINUS public DateTime?FeedbackSharedDateTime { get; set; }. =  public string AuditorAHT { get; set; }

Answer (score 0):

Is it because your duration is 00：00：00：016?If so,it is the default format of milliseconds.If you don't want milliseconds.You can use:

```
string stringAHT = duration.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
```

If you want to change other format,you can use string.Format like this:

```
string stringAHT1 = string.Format("{0:D2}h:{1:D2}m:{2:D2}s",
                        24*duration.Days+duration.Hours,
                        duration.Minutes,
                        duration.Seconds);
```

This will get a format like `xxh:xxm:xxs`

Here is a demo:

```
DateTime d1 = new DateTime(2020,12,1,11,31,20,11);
            DateTime d2 = new DateTime(2020, 12, 2,10,31,20,22);
            TimeSpan duration =d2 - d1;
            string stringAHT = duration.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
            string stringAHT1 = string.Format("{0:D2}:{1:D2}:{2:D2}",
                        24*duration.Days+duration.Hours,
                        duration.Minutes,
                        duration.Seconds
                        );
```

result:

stringAHT :23:00:00

stringAHT1 :23:00:00

**Update:**

```
string stringAHT1 = string.Format("{0:D2}:{1:D2}:{2:D2}:{3:D2}",
                        24 * duration.Days + duration.Hours,
                        duration.Minutes,
                        duration.Seconds,
                        duration.Milliseconds
                        );
```

result：

00：00：00：14

Comment: No success DateTime d1 = Convert.ToDateTime(newDTO.FeedbackDateTime);
                DateTime d2 = Convert.ToDateTime(newDTO.FeedbackSharedDateTime);
                TimeSpan duration = d2 - d1;
                string stringAHT = duration.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
                string stringAHT1 = string.Format("{0:D2}:{1:D2}:{2:D2}",
                            24 * duration.Days + duration.Hours,
                            duration.Minutes,
                            duration.Seconds
                            );
                newDTO.AuditorAHT = stringAHT1;

Comment: Can you share the data of d1,d2 and duration

Comment: d1 = 2020-12-03 15:43:59.653  : d2 = 2020-12-03 15:43:59.667 : duration = d2-d1. Which will be AHT for time spent on that specific audit by Auditor

Comment: And what is your d2 and duration?

Comment: Model Class public DateTime? d1 { get; set; }

        public DateTime? d2{ get; set; }

        public string AuditorAHT { get; set; }

Comment: No,I mean the time value,I want to use your data to test my code,so that I can find the error.Oh,I see your update in the comment.

Comment: I updated my answer,and I get 00：00：00：14.Do you want this?Or you can tell more about what you want.

Comment: I do not want to show miliseconds, It should show hh:mm:ss Example Auditor spent 5 mins 20 seconds so it should be 00:05:20

Comment: Yes,but your result is 14 miliseconds,and it is smaller than 1 second.

Comment: @RiyazShaikh Have you tried using `d1` and `d2` values that have a difference of more than 1 second?
As far as I can see, the code seems fine, but in the example given, the `duration` is, in fact, too small (less than a second).

Comment: Let me try with long duration and see what I get. Will surely notify you

Comment: Here is a result 00:00:00:16

Comment: Let me try one more with a long duration

Comment: Another one and this one seems to not bring another 00:00:00:00

Comment: No success :( what is that I am doing wrong

Comment: 1 second=1000 Milliseconds,00:00:00:16 is still smaller than 1 second.Have a try `DateTime d1 = new DateTime(2020,12,1,11,31,23,11);
            DateTime d2 = new DateTime(2020, 12, 2,10,31,20,22);TimeSpan duration = d1- d2;``d1` and `d2` values will have a difference of more than 1 second.